Is there a way to find all programs that produced a sound in the last X minutes on Windows 10+?
I have a problem that my laptop has started seemingly randomly producing a certain sound and I can't find which program is causing it. Since it's random (at least I haven't been able to find the pattern/reliably trigger it) just staring at volume mixer isn't a realistic solution (not that it's much useful in win 11) and the sound is short enough (~1sec) that trying to open the mixer/some other volume tracking program as it happens is impossible.
Is there a way to find out which programs played a sound (if not this specific one) in the last N minutes/seconds so I could use it right after the sound plays to pinpoint the culprit?

This question is similar to: Windows 10 - find out where sound is coming from. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Destroy666 that (and many similar questions) deal with finding out which application is producing sound right now, which is not applicable to my case.

There isn't a system-wide log of sound signals. Individual applications may log events that trigger sounds, but while you WANT to be able to see the source of sounds after they play, this is probably not going to be possible in Windows.

@music2myear while it does seem like there is no built-in way to do that, I don't see why there couldn't be some 3rd-paty solution.

Most likely, a brief sound is one of the Windows System Sounds, such as those for Calendar Reminder, Critical Battery Alarm, or Device Disconnect.


Press Windows and type sounds.

Select Change system sounds.

Step through the list of Program Events, clicking Test for each to see if you recognize the sound.
N.B. Some sounds are shared by multiple events, so don't stop at the first match.


For example, one common annoyance is that a USB device occasionally disconnects and reconnects, sometimes due to a loose connection, but often for no discernible reason. That causes the Device Diconnect, followed by the Device Connect sounds.
Once you find the event that produces the sound, you can trace it back to the cause. You can also change the sounds for each event, using any short .WAV file, or remove the sound -- at the risk of missing an alert to an important event.

Thanks! I've checked all sounds, and they are not coming from windows. At least it let me eliminate this source. Now I'm thinking it's either random chrome tab or slack. Will monitor those.

@DanM., Sorry that it wasn't simply a system sound. You might try Microsoft/Sysinternals Process Monitor, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon , which possibly could log the time that a process starts.
